# How to handle Bad date external representation '0' in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a field in my data which is currently a string and I need to convert it to a date. I intended to use the DATE() function but when I do so I get a Bad date external representation '0' error. Is there a way in Netezza to handle such errors such as skip them or replace them with 00/00/00?

Also, how can I find which rows are causing the issue? Right now I have no visibility of which rows are causing me issues.

Comment: Please provide sample sample values of good dates and bad dates.

Comment: Please note that the year 0000 is not valid. When we started numbering the years from the birth of Christ, they used Roman numbering system where 0 is not possible, so 0001 comes directly after -0001, and on netezza only positive years are possible (as per sql standard)